# Joomla get class from Form Field

Tags: forms, class, joomla, field, components

I have a Joomla fields form  like this:

```
<field 
    name="visible"
    type="list"
    label="COM_VISIBLE"
    description="COM_VISIBLE_TOOLTIP"
    class="inputbox">
        <option value="0">COM_HIDDEN</option>
        <option value="1">COM_VISIBLE</option>
 </field>
```

How to get class properties??

```
$field->label and $field->input it's ok... 
but with 

    JFormFieldList
    JFormFieldMedia
    JFormFieldHidden
    JFormFieldMedia  

return "Undefined property: JFormFieldList::$class in... ()"
```

Otherwise it's empty

Comment: UPDATE: SOLVED $class = $this->form->getFieldAttribute($field->fieldname, 'class', '', $field->group);

Comment: Please add your solution as a proper answer below

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED

```
$class = $this->form->getFieldAttribute($field->fieldname, 'class', '', $field->group); –
```

Comment: Hi! Since some time, Joomla has its own StackExchange site: [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com). I recommend you asking your future [tag:joomla]-related questions there. Joomla gurus are now primarily around **joomla.stackexchange.com**.

Comment: thanks! I have created new account on joomla.stackexchange.com